# Weka commmandline and strings

Tags: command-line-interface, weka, classification

I'd like to do some text classification (Naive Bayes) with Weka using the simple cli (command line), but I have one problem. Weka can't handle strings, they have to be converted.
But how can I convert the strings in my arff file through cli?

sentences.arff example

```
@relation data set

@attribute text string
@attribute class {swedish,'?',english}

@data
'detta är en svensk text',swedish
'this is an english text',english
'what is the name of this book?',english
'vilken färg är en liten stuga?',swedish
'you are the best',english
'en enstaka fjäder i hatten fördröjer livet ett tag',swedish
'detta är en annan svensk text',swedish
```

I'm using the following command to create a model

```
java weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t data.arff -d data.model
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [StringToWordVector](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html) to change text attributes to numeric values. Most classifiers in weka can not work with text values, see [Working with textual data](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+WEKA). After that you can use  [NaiveBayes](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/bayes/NaiveBayes.html)
 normally.

```
java weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -i datasets\sentences.arff > datasets\sentencesWordVector.arff
java weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t datasets\sentencesWordVector.arff -c 1 -x 3
```

Note that I need to use 3 folds (**-x 3**) since your example's instance number is shorter than default value 10.
I also used class index 1 (**-c 1**).

In my computer, I get following Confusion Matrix. Quite normal since your examples does not have any instance with '?'.

```
=== Confusion Matrix ===

a b c   <-- classified as
4 0 0 | a = swedish
0 0 0 | b = ?
0 0 3 | c = english
```

Comment: thanks.
Should I do the same with the sentences I like to test on? After creating the model and converting the test files
I get the error:
training and test set are not compatible

Comment: @Thomas You should do it for all of documents. Please upvote and mark it as answer if it helped you.